# regular expression pattern for string not working as I think it should

Tags: regex

I have the following string that occurs in a file

```
stat -f
-------Begin------
key    : value
key    : value
key    : value


-------end---------
stat < d
some other content here
stat -f
-------Begin------
key    : value
key    : value
key    : value


-------end---------
stat < d
```

and want to extract the key value pair, which are not always the same. Isn't this regex correct?

```
^[a-z]*\s*:\s*\d+
```

I tried it on [here](https://goo.gl/Q7pNIW) for this string

```
stat-f
------Begin------
key    :     0
key    :     1
key    :     2
-------end-------
stat < d
```

but I get no match. Any help on how regexp works in simple (as possible of course) words?

Comment: Try adding `m` flag. It will force `^` to match beginning of a line.

Comment: I did but it still won't  match all pairs.

Comment: `which are not always the same` what does it mean? unique key-value pairs? or different strings with same patterns?

Comment: @Apostolos you also need the `g` (global) flag.

Comment: @karthikmanchala yes it means that the key isn't always the same within the ----begin----- and ------endparts------.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/(\w+)\s+:\s+(\w+)/g
```

1. One or more word characters with capturing group.
2. One or more whitespace characters
3. Colon
4. One or more whitespace characters
5. One or more word characters with capturing group.
6. Use global flag (g)

Comment: @Apostolos: Your regex also works. Just use `m` flag and also `g` to rerurn all matches. See [debuggex demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TQmE0Nf_hL5jZwBv) where you have all matches highlighted by default. Setting capturing groups is a bit different thing though.